# How to make web site that is compatible to mobile(Blackberry,Android,iPhone) screen sizes?

Tags: mobile-website

Hi I am developing a site for desktop.The site renders the contents for desktop size.But when I see it in mobile the content is not properly rendered. 
How can I make a site that fits all mobile screen sizes say Blackberry,Android,iPhone, etc. Can anybody mention any articles. I know only HTML. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember looking into myself a while ago and finding [this video tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-a-crash-course-in-css-media-queries/) on net-tuts+ to be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to make a single site that looks good on both mobile and desktop. Resolution is not the only problem, the very way the user interacts with you site changes on a mobile device. That said, the typical thing to do is to have a mobile style sheet which is loaded for mobile, and a desktop sheet for desktop. You might even go so far as to limit some of your content on mobile to make the page lighter.

I found http://mobiforge.com to be a good source of info.